# Overleaf, where to find missing { or output.gls?

Tags: overleaf, debugging

I am working on a document in LaTex with overleaf when I noticed this error:

```
<to be read again> 
                   \let 
l.21 ...entrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{18}}}
                                                  %
A left brace was mandatory here, so I've put one in.
You might want to delete and/or insert some corrections
so that I will find a matching right brace soon.
(If you're confused by all this, try typing `I}' now.)

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.21 ...entrycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{18}}}
                                                  %
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

The problem is that it says the error is a missing `{` in a file called `output.gls`. From what I understand this is an auto generated file created by the glossary, which shouldn't simply miss a `{`. So the issue can't be with that file but must be with my code. I attempted to resolve this by commenting out sections of code I wrote since the last working version, and I did find out which line causes it, however I don't understand why:

```
\newglossaryentry{density}
{
    name=\ensuremath{\kappa},
    description={$ \in  \mathbb{K}$. Density scalar field over $\Omega$. In practice we parameterize it in terms of \gls{density parameter}
    }
}

\newglossaryentry{density parameter}
{
    name=\ensuremath{\alpha},
    description={$\in [0,1]^F$.% Parameter used to describe \gls{density}
    }
}
```

The problem stems from `In practice we parameterize it in terms of \gls{density parameter}`, the error disappears if I comment out this sentence. I tried making a minimum working example but as a comment below pointed out the error was unrelated. The example was:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\title{Test}
\date{September 2021}


\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{density}
{
    name=\ensuremath{\kappa},
    description={$ \in  \mathbb{K}$. Density scalar field over $\Omega$. In practice we parameterize it in terms of \gls{density parameter}
    }
}

\newglossaryentry{density parameter}
{
    name=\ensuremath{\alpha},
    description={$\in [0,1]^F$. Parameter used to describe \gls{density}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Minimal Example}

Calling \gls{density} is causing an error.
But only calling \gls{density parameter} does not.
Commenting out the description of the $\kappa$ after ``In practice...'' fixes the error as well.

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

So while I could just comment out that part of the description it seems clear to me I am just misunderstanding how the glossary works and wanted to ask what mistake I made.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The error messages says that the error is at `\mathbb`, macro undefined. Load the package `amsfonts` or `amssymb`.

Comment: Edited out the example code since it wasn't illustrating the problem. Unfortunately this means I don't understand this error enough to even make a minimal example code.

Comment: Please provide a small *complete* sample document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows the problem. Otherwise there is no way to guess what's wrong. Removing the MWE is the wrong direction to go. Fix the MWE such that it shows the problem

Comment: in your edit you have removed the error message that shows the source of the problem, the solution for which is in the first comment.

Comment: My original question included what I though was a minimal complete sample showing the error. gernot correctly pointed out it was a completely unrelated error, so I deleted it.
I honestly don't even understand the error enough to be able to make a minimal example...

Comment: I added the sample again, but it doesn't have the same error as the original code.

Comment: There does not appear to be any error in your example.